# Is there a way to list all tests with ScalaTest?

Tags: scala, maven, scalatest

I'm trying to inventory all the tests in a Scala project and I'd prefer to not have to do this manually (there are hundreds) or write a script (I'd hope something already exists). I assume that there must be a way to list all the tests as you can tell ScalaTest or Maven to run all tests in a project so they must be doing some enumeration of tests behind the scenes. The end goal here is to get a list of all tests with their runtimes, to know which are the slow ones to focus on optimizing first (I mention this in case there is a more straightforward way of getting this information, I'd love to know).

Comment: I'd assume the "enumeration" is searching a class path, or its subset, for non-abstract classes with default constructor and implementing some suite parent class. That would get you a list of suites. AFAIK you cannot get more granularity than that because there is no mechanism for running a single test in a Scalatest suite. The suite is being run, constructing tests in runtime, and the library just use the reporter to output the results to some output stream.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to list down the tests and you have `sbt`, then the command below will help -

`sbt "show test:definedTests"`